# Inf file PreCopySection

Tags: inf

I have found [PreCopySection] section in some inf files. Often it ha only the following content:

```
[PreCopySection]
HKR,,NoSetupUI,,1
```

I tried to find any documentation on it using MSDN and Google with no luck. The file doesn't contain any other mentions of "PreCopySection" string so I beleive it couldn't be created with any other directive.
Does anyone know its format and what it stand for?

Thanks